# How to create dummy variable for categorical variable in R?? For performing regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I want to create dummy variables for 1 independent variables in my model. Below is an example how my dataset looks.Y is my dependent variable and Var1, Var2, Var3 are independent variables.

Dataset:

Y Var1 Var2 Var3
1 30 N3 45
0 43 N2 56
0 56 N2 76
1 67 N1 89
0 77 N2 99

Desired output:
Y Var1 Var2 Var3
1 30 0 45
0 43 1 56
0 56 1 76
1 67 2 89
0 77 1 99

Can we run this with using the loop as we have 3 indep. variables? It will be very helpful if anyone guides me through the R code?

That how to convert a Categorical variable into the continuous variable for applying the regression. How to create dummy variables for Var2

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Basically the answer is "Don't do this". You do not need to create dummy variables in R. Look at the factor function. It's basic R concept so you should go back to whatever text you are studying from and find out how to define factors and levels. In fact, the variable Var2 would already be a factor class if you used any of the read.* functions to create a dataframe. By default, stringsAsFactors is TRUE in those functions and in `data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

Actually linear regression works for categorical variables. See http://r4ds.had.co.nz/model-basics.html#formulas-and-model-families, scroll down to 23.4.1.

For instance, with your example, if I understand you correctly, all variables are continuous, except that Var2 is categorical. I generated some pseudo data and ran `lm` on it. So far it didn't throw any error. Here's the example:

```
# Generate pseudo data
df <- data.frame(Y = 2:21 + rnorm(20),
              Var1 = 1:20 + rnorm(20),
              Var2 = sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 20, replace = TRUE),
              Var3 = rnorm(20, 10, 3))

# The linear regression model
mod <- lm(Y ~ Var1 + Var2 + Var3, data = df)
```

And here are the coefficients returned:

```
 Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Var1        Var2C        Var2G        Var2T         Var3  
    2.34602      0.98814     -1.78821     -0.44720     -0.70167     -0.06736
```

Apparently it kind of worked, since Var1 is constructed to be almost proportional to Y. With n categories; you get a coefficient for n-1 categories since the remaining one is determined by what you get for the n-1. Behind the scene R is just converting the categorical to 0s and 1s, 1 when an observation is in say category A, and 0 if not; similarly for other categories. You really don't need a dummy variable if a variable is categorical.

I also tried it when the dependent variable is categorical; `lm` will give you a warning,

```
using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

but you still get a model, though the predictions are continuous and depends on how you order your categories (often the ordering is just arbitrary), so it calls into question how meaningful the prediction is. Anyway, there're many cases where an independent variable is categorical, like genotype and sex, but I've never seen a case when the dependent variable is categorical and linear regression is still used.